# Помощь по регулярному выражению в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Друзья!
Помогите пожалуйста, необходимо реализовать следующую возможность. Нужно дать вводить пользователю только данные ограниченного формата.
Поле должно иметь размер 12 или 14 символов при этом допустимо вводить только 1 буквенный символ 1 пробел а все остальное цифры при этом пробелов и буквенных символов может и не быть но размер должен быть точным.
`^(([a-zA-Z ]?[0-9]){12}|([a-zA-Z ]?[0-9]){14})$` - этот не подходит.

Comment: _этот не подходит._ - почему не подходит?

Comment: потому что если не вводить буквенный символ или пробел то кол-во символов будет не 12 и 14 а 13 и 15

Comment: не понял. 13 только цифр - это разрешенная комбинация или нет?

Comment: всего можно ввести 12 или 14 цифр это определенное число не зависит от того ввели вы буквенные символы или пробел если ввели 1 букву то тогда можно ввести только 11 цифр

Comment: ага, а в чем тогда заключается проблема с _потому что если не вводить буквенный символ или пробел то кол-во символов будет не 12 и 14 а 13 и 15_?

Comment: Мне необходимо чтобы пользователь ввел ровно 12 или 14 символов всего, без разницы будет ли он вводить символьные знаки или пробел или нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^((?!(.*[a-z ].*[a-z ].*))([0-9a-z ]{12})|(?!(.*[a-z ].*[a-z ].*))([0-9a-z ]{14}))$/gi
```

https://regex101.com/r/NIk0cs/1